# Deploying a war file from Artifactory to a server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory

Each commit to our code result in regression tests and deployment of a war file to Artifactory.

We would like to deploy once a day the last successfully tested war.
What would be the best way to do this? We use Jenkins as our CI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to save on storage in Artifactory, I'd suggest setup [snapshot cleanup](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Cleaning-upUniqueSnapshots) instead. You'll always have couple of last sucessfuly tested wars and you won't polute your Artifactory with too many old snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second job that copies the latest artifact ([Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)) from your build job and then deploys the artifact.  The second job can be scheduled to run once a day.